# Set depth of pages to fetch

Tags: loop

I have a custom loop to display the children pages of a parent which works well - however, I want to be able to limit the depth of the pages to display. I only want 1 level of pages to be displayed, so nothing more than 1 level should appear. Current code is below - can anyone help modify/extend this to get it to work, returning just 1 level of pages // thanks!

```
<?php
    $ids = array();
    $pages = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
    if ($pages) {
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $ids[] = $page->ID;
        }
    }
    $paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
    $args = array(
        "paged" => $paged,
        "post__in" => $ids,
        "posts_per_page" => 6,
        "post_type" => "page"
    );
    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <div class="feedItemWrapper wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_fadeInUp fadeInUp">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full', array() ); ?>
    <div class="feedItemContentWrapper">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: use `parent` instead of `child_of`

Comment: Many Thanks - thats great!

Comment: I would avoid `query_posts`, _use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the main query_, or use a `WP_Query` loop for secondary post loops. `query_posts` has lots of issues, and rarely a situation in theme/plugin development where a better alternative isn't available ( 1 in a million odds of it happening ). By using it for the main listing on a page you're also doubling the number of database requests and gaining a performance penalty, as well as several more obscure bugs you won't be aware of ( e.g. if the main query has 3 pages of results, but yours has 4, the 4th page might 404 )

Comment: Also, functions such as `get_pages` are equivalent to `get_posts` but with extra quirks, which is likely the reason you ran into this issue. If you can provide more information about where this code is running on your site, when it runs, and what kind of pages it runs on, is it a sidemenu? A footer/header section? Does it show on pages? Or is this a set of custom page templates for a catalog/index? Context will help greatly